# How do I create a state to handle events in my form?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

How do I create a state to toggle the buttons in my form between true or false(yes and no)?

I'm trying to handle the state with a function:

```js
const onMutate = (e) => {
        // toggle
        buttonState = !buttonState;

        // Files
        if (e.target.files) {
            formData = {
                ...formData,
                images: e.target.files
            };
        }

        // texts/number/boolean
        if (!e.target.files) {
            formData = {
                ...formData,
                [e.target.id]: buttonState ?? e.target.value
            };
        }
    };
```

My State:

```js
let buttonState = false;
```

I put the function (onMutate) in my events:

```
on:click={onMutate}
on:Change={onMutate}
```

Ok. I can switch my buttons between yes or no (true or false) with the 'on:click' event, but when I type into the input, I fire the same event and get true or false in my inputs. I know it's an issue about javascript more than Svelte. I know where the problem is:

```
// texts/number/boolean
            if (!e.target.files) {
                formData = {
                    ...formData,
                    [e.target.id]: buttonState ?? e.target.value
                };
            }
```

But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I notice that are not skipping buttonState with '??', because is a boolean. What is the best way to refactor this code?

Comment: A Good Samaritan to help me?

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML for the button you want to be changed? And more important, can you please explain when it should change and show us the HTML from the "Trigger" element? I assume it is based on some selected files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to decipher what exactly you want to accomplish. But I think I was able to find something that is most likely the root of your issue. Namely that you get `true` and `false` in the `formData`.

This comes about because you are using the `??` operator. It works the following way (with the example of `a ?? b`): [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

- if a is `null` or `undefined` then it will return `b`
- in all other cases it will return `a`

In your case `buttonState` is neither `null` nor `undefined` so, the value of the expression will be the value of `buttonState`, ie: `true` or `false`.

I can assume that you wanted to use a logic where if the `buttonState` is `true`, then include the value of the input, otherwise don't.

The proper expression for this is (using the [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)):

`buttonState ? e.target.value : null`

This will produce the value of the input if `buttonState` is `true`, and `null` if the `buttonState` is `false`. You can, of course, use other values instead of `null` for the false state.

---

Some additional notes:

The buttonState is toggled at each event, including on the `onChange` event. I don't know if it's intentional but seems odd, that when you type something in an input box your button flips on an off. It would be more logical if the button would have its own event handler which could be as simple as:

`<button on:click={()=> buttonState=!buttonState}>....`

Note #2: It's really useful to people who would like to help you out if you provide a small working mockup in a REPL with and link to it in your question. It's good that you provided some part of your code, but it's still hard to figure out how it all supposed to work. I know it's extra work, but will get you faster and better responses.